# enum или boolean члены класса что лучше?

Tags: c++, enum

Продолжаю штудировать самоучитель Шилтда и обратил внимание что в одном из своих примеров он объевляет enum список для членов класса, которые во многих других языках программирования были бы просто булево свойствами:

```
// Fruit.h
#pragma once

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


enum yn {no, yes};
enum color {red, yellow, green, orange};

class Fruit {
public:
    enum yn annual;
    enum yn perennial;
    enum yn tree;
    enum yn tropical;
    enum color color;
    char name[40];
};

class Apple : public Fruit{
    enum yn cooking;
    enum yn crunchy;
    enum yn eating;
public:
    void seta(char*, enum color, enum yn, enum yn, enum yn);
    void show();
};

class Orange : public Fruit {
    enum yn juice;
    enum yn sour;
    enum yn eating;
public:
    void seto(char*, enum color, enum yn, enum yn, enum yn);
    void show();
};



// Fruit.cpp
#include "Fruit.h"

char* c[] =
{
    "red", "yellow", "green", "orange"
};

void out(enum yn);

void Apple::seta(char *name, enum color color, enum yn cooking, 
enum yn  crunchy, enum yn eating)  
{
    strcpy(this->name, name);
    annual = no;
    perennial = yes;
    tree = yes;
    tropical = no;
    this->color = color;
    this->cooking = cooking;
    this->crunchy = crunchy;
    this->eating = eating;
}

void Orange::seto(char *name, enum color color, enum yn juice, 
enum yn sour,  enum yn eating)
{
    strcpy(this->name, name);
    annual = no;
    perennial = yes;
    tree = yes;
    tropical = yes;
    this->color = color;
    this->juice = juice;
    this->sour = sour;
    this->eating = eating;
}

void Apple::show()
{
    cout << name << " яблоко — это: " << "\n";
    cout << "Однолетнее растение: "; out(annual);
    cout << "Многолетнее растение: "; out(perennial);
    cout << "Дерево: "; out(tree);
    cout << "Тропическое: "; out(tropical);
    cout << "Цвет: " << c[color] << "\n";
    cout << "Легко приготавливается: "; out(cooking);
    cout << "Хрустит на зубах: "; out(crunchy);
    cout << "Съедобное: "; out(eating);
    cout << endl;
}

void Orange::show()
{
    cout << name << " яблоко — это: " << "\n";
    cout << "Однолетнее растение: "; out(annual);
    cout << "Многолетнее растение: "; out(perennial);
    cout << "Дерево: "; out(tree);
    cout << "Тропическое: "; out(tropical);
    cout << "Цвет: " << c[color] << "\n";
    cout << "Годится для приготовления сока: "; out(juice);
    cout << "Кислый: "; out(sour);
    cout << "Съедобное: "; out(eating);
    cout << endl;
 }

 void out( enum yn x)
 {
      if (x == no) cout << "нет" << endl;
      else cout << "да" << endl;
 };
```

Я предположил что возможно таким образом автор избегает создание новых сущностей и экономит память, ссылаясь на уже созданный список вместо объявления временных булево констант. Прав ли я в своих догадках? Насколько корректно создавать такие списки для булево членов класса и стоит ли перенимать данную практику в реальных проектах.

Дополнительные вопросы, если позволите
2.1 Стоит ли в данном случае делать метод out inline методом?
2.2 Стоит ли прислушиваться к предупреждениям компилятора и избегать использования strcpy, заменив его yf strcpy_с? От каких опасностей он пытается меня предостеречь?

Comment: Я не видел книгу, но может быть это просто глава, посвященная перечислениям? :)

Comment: Нет, данная глава посвящена наследованию. К enum даже нет пояснений. Вероятно таким образом обеспечивается дополнительная нагрузка на читателя и подготовка к более сложным главам, тем не менее по enum в этой главе никаких комментариев нет.

Comment: `strcpy_с`? Может `strcpy_s`?

Comment: "...вместо объявления временных булево констант". А что вы имеете в виду под этим? Что такое "объявление временных булево констант"?

Comment: разве при передаче значения true/false не создается временная константа с таки же значением?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никакого отношения к экономии памяти это не имеет.

Такая (или похожая) практика может быть полезной, когда в программе присутствуют функции с большим числом булевских по своей сути параметров, которые идут вереницей. Код, в котором в функцию передается цепочка булевских констант

```
foo(..., true, false, false, false, true, ...);
```

трудночитаем, ибо назначение каждого параметра в точке вызова ясно не сразу. Если же придать таким параметрам свои отдельные enum типы с именованными членами (даже если эти параметры по сути - просто "булевские"), то вызов функции будет читаться легче

```
foo(..., ENABLE_IO, NO_LOG, NO_ABORT, DISABLE_CACHE, YES_SORT, ...);
```

или с использованием scoped enums

```
foo(..., IO::ENABLE, LOG::NO, ABORT::NO, CACHE::DISABLE, SORT::YES, ...);
```

Также контроль типов при использовании этого приема защищает вас от указания аргументов в неправильном порядке (т.е. например от случайного "сдвига" цепочки аргументов влево или вправо).

В вашем примере, однако, делается не это. Поэтому особого смысла в том, что происходит в приведенном вами коде, не видно. Зачем могло понадобиться заменять огульный булевский тип на не менее огульный самодельный "булевский" тип - не ясно.

P.S. `const` - нужен

```
const char* c[] =
{
    "red", "yellow", "green", "orange"
};
```

Как, впрочем, и в множестве других мест.

Comment: во множестве других, вы имеете ввиду что сами перечисления тоже сделать константами? Там больше особенно негде что-то делать константами.

Comment: @Sergey Kostin: Нет. В функциях `seta`, `seto` параметр должен быть `const char *`. Методы типа `show` сами должны быть `const`. Если это учебник, то возможно он до этой темы пока не добрался.

Comment: @AnT если это не какая-то новая редакция, то тот учебник делался до того, как scoped enums перестали быть расширением. Но это был стиль учебника, возможно под влиянием  стиля именований по рекомендации Oracle.Такие же вещи делали разработчики Qt и X11, используя перечисления или константы для описания двоичных состояний (Yes\No, On\Off, Enabled\Disabled)  что вызывало проблемы с конфликтом имен.

Answer (score 3):

> возможно таким образом автор избегает создание новых сущностей и экономит память

Никакой экономии памяти тут нет. Есть только наглядность. Делайте так, как вам удобней (например, enum будет полезен, если потом захочется его расширить до `{ no, yes, maybe, ... }`)

> Стоит ли в данном случае делать метод out inline методом?

Почему бы и нет? В любом случае спецификатор `inline` - не строгое указание компилятору, он может поступить по-своему. А вот расположение кода внутри определения класса может быть просто наглядней, особенно если там одна-две строчки.

> От каких опасностей он пытается меня предостеречь?

От случайного переполнения строки назначения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не могли бы пояснить в каком случае есть риск переполнить строку назначения и как можно этого избежать? Ввести дополнительную проверку на длину принимаемой строки?

Comment: @SergeyKostin, если коротко - например, использовать `stdup()` (чтобы гарантировано выделить для строки назначения нужное количество байт), а в случае C++ вообще не использовать С-строки. На самом деле это тема для отдельного вопроса, тут может быть много вариантов (но к C++ вопрос, строго говоря, отношения не имеет, только к C).

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых ситуациях `enum` может оказаться лучше `bool`: если вам вдруг захотелось добавить к набору значений `maybe`, `unknown` или что-либо в этом духе. Не думаю, что тут экономится память.

Comment: То есть передача в функции аргументов в виде : true, false констант не требовало бы от программы выделения памяти? В с++ только мы управляем памятью или компилятор для своих целей тоже использует память например для обслуживания этих временных констант?

Comment: @SergeyKostin, передача аргументов к выделению памяти не имеет никакого отношения.